# How to retrieve key value of child node from firebase database using firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to get a specific key value for my firebase database in firebase cloud function.

The key value is under the node. "fcmToken"/"receiverUid" where receiverUid is the unique Key value.

```js
admin
      .database()
      .ref(/fcmToken/${receiverUid})
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        var getInstanceIdPromise = snapshot.key;
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      })
```

ESlint keeps giving me error either return or catch.

How should i fix this code so i am getting value from fcmToken/{variable}/key value?

Comment: did you try the answer? @frankcrest

Answer (score 0):

If your database is like the following(`fcmToken/{variable}/key value`):

```
fcmToken
    uid
     tokenName : food
```

then do the following to get the value of `food`:

```
admin
  .database()
  .ref(/fcmToken/${receiverUid})
  .once("value")
  .then(snapshot => {
    var getInstanceIdPromise = snapshot.tokenName;
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  })
```

in your case `key` is a property of `datasnapshot` which gives you your current location in the database, which is the value of `${receiverUid}`.

From the docs:

> [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key)
>
> The key (last part of the path) of the location of this DataSnapshot.